# Do I have to keep my maps in Far Cry 5?

Tags: far-cry-5

Throughout the campaign so far, I have been collecting maps which are adding locations of interest to my main map, but I still have the option to sell these maps I found to a vendor. If I sell these maps, does it remove those points of interest it added from my main map? I cannot find an option to buy back from vendors, so I don’t want to accidentally sell them. However, with these maps in my inventory, I am almost positive if I do the action of Quick Sell(one button to sell all pelts), it will sell my maps too.

Is this the same for fishing magazines which provided fishing locations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have been wondering the same thing, sold my fishing mags and the spots they discovered we’re still displayed on my map so I think its a safe bet to say you can sell them. As far as the maps you can totaly sell them, if you go to your inventory after you’ve collected them it says “Points of interest have been added to your map. You can safely sell this item now”

Answer (score 3):

The maps you find in the world are just a way for you to add local landmarks to your actual map. Selling those maps do not remove that area from your map, they're revealed forever. You can safely sell them. The game even mentions that when you find your first map I think, or maybe when you first sell your junk.

Answer (score 0):

The maps can be sold as soon as you pick them up. It gives you a brief message saying that you can now sell the map when you pick it up. You can also double check this by going to your inventory. If you select the map, it will tell you a bit about that map and state that you can now safely sell that item.

The only map I haven’t sold is the Clutch Nixon map. It doesn’t say if I can sell it and it just neat, so I kept it.